# USB Stick Write Problems

Tags: 14.04, usb, usb-drive

Ubuntu 14.04 with software up-to-date as of 25 September, 2014, 
System 76 Gazelle Professional laptop, model gazp8, 
SanDisk Cruzer U 16GB thumb drive.

For the past two weeks I have had significant problems writing files to this USB stick.  Writes will either fail altogether, or they will appear to complete, but the stick will fail to unmount/eject properly, and the device will be unrecognizable by this and other computers afterward.

When attempting to write files, the copy progress indicator will move rapidly from 0% to 95% or so, and then the copy dialog box will simply hang.

I'm having this problem with files between the sizes of 9.1MB and 1.2GB.
I have deleted and re-created the partition, formatting in FAT, NTFS, and a few Linux-specific file systems.  None of these actions have alleviated the problem.  And ultimately I do need to transfer these files to both Macs and PCs.  I also used one of the destination computers to format the stick, but as soon as I plug it into my Gazelle, the problem reappears, and most often leaves the stick unusable.  But if I format the stick, it works just fine on other computers thereafter.

I read through some other seemingly-related questions/answers, and none of the solutions I've found thus far have helped.  However, I found one mention that the flush option should not appear for the thumb drive in the `/etc/mtab` file.  The flush option does appear by default whenever the drive is mounted. I do not know how to change this.

Also, I read that the default block size may be too large, but the instructions I found on how to modify that did not work, which is to say, the commands failed, or were unrecognized on my computer.

Any ideas or suggestions?